# git: Log for 'master' only goes back to date bug?

Tags: git, date, logging, diff

When I do the following in my working copy:

```
> git diff 'master@{1 hour ago}'
```

It prints

```
warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Thu, 14 Jan 2016 15:37:11 -0500.
```

Yet when I do `git log master`, it clearly goes back farther:

```
commit bb9c80fb1c3895a9c11f7a60710497cc8406e71f
Author: Andy Edwards <andy@example.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 12 22:44:21 2016 -0600
...
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a git bug?

Comment: The `master@` is using the reflog, which correlates to your local repository creation, and not the commit dates

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @AndrewC does `HEAD@` mean something different from `master@`?  I'm getting the same warning for both.

Comment: @merlin2011 I'm trying to make a script that periodically checks if files have changed and if so, regenerates some derived data and commits it back to the repo.  I figured out another way to do it, but this still seems strange to me.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to modify this question to ask about how to refer to the commit log, not the reflog

Comment: Wait, I just grokked the problem with what I'm trying to do...in distributed version control, it's impossible for the commit history to be linear in time isn't it? :)

Comment: @AndrewC I think your comment would be a satisfactory answer, if you want more reputation

Comment: This may be helpful, if you are just looking for an easy way to figure out which commit to checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488492/28324

Answer (score 1):

Use [git-whatchanged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged) instead.

```
git whatchanged --since="1 hour ago" --patch
```