# Checkout old commit from git based on date

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am trying to retrieve an old commit from git, due to incompatibility with another project (which shares this code).  The git repo is OpenZWave.

I found a post on SO saying to issue command:

```
git checkout @{14.days.ago}
```

But that results in:

```
warning: Log for '' only goes back to Wed, 23 May 2018 08:02:05 -0400.
HEAD is now at 77a05ed... Update hs-ms100plus.xml
```

I can't figure out what's wrong - clearly there are older commits than today's date.  What is wrong with this command?  (And will that command result in my clone being replaced with code from 14 days ago)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax `@{XXX.days.ago}` refers to the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), a local history kept by Git in addition to the history as shown by e.g. `git log`. So, `@{14.days.ago}` means "where `HEAD` pointed to 14 days ago *on this repository, on my computer*", not "the commit made 14 days ago" (which was probably made on another repository on another computer).

You can instead:

- Get the commit id, with e.g.

```
git log --before 14.days.ago -1
```

- Checkout this commit:

```
git checkout
```

Comment: OK - that log search worked too.  But 'git checkout' did not replace the code in my clone with the code from 14 days ago...everything is still dated today

Comment: What does `git status` say after the checkout?

Answer (score 4):

**Why it didn't work?**

`git checkout @{14.days.ago}` tries to restore *local state of specific repository* at the given time, based on reflog (the record of all commits HEAD pointed to in past). If this is a fresh clone, it won't work.

So, the nice syntax won't work and you need to find some commit done a year ago, and check it out by the hash. How to do that?

**How to find a commit submitted a year ago?**

I would just try finding the proper commit in `gitk`, scrolling through a year of commits shouldn't be an issue in most cases. However, you could also grep the log, like this:

```
git log --date=iso | grep -C3 2017-05-
```

or, if you know there were commits submitted on the specific day, like this:

```
git log --date=iso | grep -C3 2017-05-23
```

Short explanation:

- `--date=iso` ensures that the date is displayed in an easily greppable way.
- `-C3` option makes `grep` include 3 adjacent lines, up and down, so that for each commit we capture the line with hash and the first line of commit message.

Comment: OK - that worked, and based on the ID I found I tried 'git checkout 8b7c9ca5b389c1bf9dcef68593a5a9f63c6b829b' and that command was accepted, but the code in my clone has not changed.  Is there another command required to pull down the old code?

Comment: Ah, you answered while I was typing mine. Good answer too, thanks (I'm keeping mine because the `git log -1 --before` may help, too).

Comment: @MatthieuMoy `git log -1 --before` is a lot cleaner solution, upvoted :). Mine is just the first hack that came to my mind.

Comment: @TSG: How do you check that the code isn't changed? I'm asking cause in other comment you mention "everything being dated today". If you mean modification dates, it is working as intended. See `git status` to check what commits you are supposed to have checked out. You can try `git diff master` or something similar to see that the files actually changed (I mean, I suppose they did; they definitely should).

Comment: You're right - I was looking at dates in 'ls' output