# git warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to a date? How to refer to remote branch instead of local branch?

Tags: git

When I execute the below command in a working branch (checked out from remotes/origin/master today):

```
git checkout master
git diff --name-status "@{2 days ago}" "@{now}"
```

It says:

```
warning: Log for 'HEAD' only goes back to Thu, 19 Sep 2019 16:01:05 -0700.
```

Yet when I check `git log master`, it clearly goes back further back:

```
commit a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Merge: 1cfee7bc5 14583d879
Author: ABC
Date:   Wed Sep 18 14:05:51 2019 -0700

    Merge-Request: 2457 from 'CXSFA-44175' into 'master'

commit 1cfee7bc5c292c09a108e0319ddcec8ab3608887
Merge: 8ab7bc71e 80464ea73
Author: DEF
Date:   Wed Sep 18 10:03:04 2019 -0700
```

Andrew's comment in this question ([git: Log for 'master' only goes back to date bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799426/git-log-for-master-only-goes-back-to-date-bug)) says:
"The master@ is using the reflog, which correlates to your local repository creation, and not the commit dates"

But, I couldn't figure out the solution for this issue.
I just want to get the log from the remote master branch and not my local working copy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### TL;DR

This line:

> ```
> commit a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
> ```

indicates that your `master` is already in sync with your `origin/master`, so you're on the same commit.  The one caveat is, this is from your Git's *memory* of their Git, the last time your Git talked to their Git.  Run `git fetch origin` any time to have your own Git get anything new from their (`origin`'s) Git and update your `origin/*` names: now your Git's memory is up to date.  (Of course, it could be out of date a few seconds later.)

#### Long

Git can be pretty confusing.  The terminology is not very consistent and words get re-used with totally different meanings, all over the place.

In this case the warning message is just what you noted: `master@{...}` uses what Git calls the *reflogs*.  The reflogs are logs (unrelated to `git log`) of *refs* or *references*.  The name `master` is a *branch name*, which is a specific form of *reference*.  So this refers to the reflog for the ref `refs/heads/master`, and `refs/heads/master` is the long way of spelling out `master`.

So we've just seen one problem: the word *log* might mean `git log`, but it might mean something else.  That's nothing, though, compared to the word *branch!*  See, e.g., [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

To help clear up all the confusion, let's start with something more basic, though.  When you use Git, there's more than one repository involved.  You have *your* copy, I have *mine*, Fred has *his*, Alice has *hers*, and so on.  Every one of these Git repositories has branches and commits and stuff like that.  How can we keep them all straight?

There are only a few absolutes, in Git.  The main one is those hash IDs you see in your `git log` output:

> ```
> commit 1cfee7bc5c292c09a108e0319ddcec8ab3608887
> ```

and:

> ```
> commit a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd
> ```

These hash IDs are truly universal.  If *you* have commit `a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd`, your Git calls it `a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd`.  If Alice has it, *her* Git calls it `a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd` too.  *Everyone* who has *that* commit, calls it that same big ugly hash ID.  They either have that, or they don't have anything with that big ugly hash ID.

Mere humans, of course, are terrible at dealing with these hash IDs.  But we don't *have* to deal with them directly, most of the time: we have a *computer*.  Why not have *it* remember the hash IDs?  So Git does that—which is where branch names come in—but each Git repository has *its own* branch names.  Your `master` need not match Bob's `master`.  Your name `master` will hold some big ugly hash ID, but it might be different from someone else's.

To deal with that, we have our Gits remember each other's branches.  When you have your Git call up some other Git that you call `origin`, your Git has their Git list out its branch names and hash IDs.  Their Git may say *my `master` is `a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd`*.  If so, your Git makes sure you have that commit (by hash ID), getting it from their Git if not, and then your Git sets *your* `refs/remotes/origin/master` *name* to `a2d1acfe855899e7e9562a16b692aa5d1f44d5dd`.

What this means in the end is that you can tell what their Git's `master` was, the last time your Git talked to their Git, by checking to see what *your* Git's `origin/master` is now.  You can change which hash ID your `master` is; your Git will leave your `origin/master`—full name `refs/remotes/origin/master`—alone, until you have your Git call up their Git again and find out where their `master` is.

Your *reflogs* remember, for you, what your Git put in your references.  Every time your Git updates your `master`, your Git stores a new entry in your Git's `refs/heads/master` reflog.  This works for your remote-tracking names too: every time your Git updates your `refs/remotes/origin/master`, your memory of `origin`'s master, your Git stores a new entry in your Git's `refs/remotes/origin/master` reflog.  So you *can* look in your reflogs, but that's to see what you used to have in your own refs.  That does not look at any actual *commits*, at least not right away; these reflog entries hold one hash ID each, and you can use that to find commits.

Reflog entries are private to each Git.  Your Git will not get reflog entries from their Git.  You cannot see what they did to their refs over time, not this way anyway.  You can only see what your Git did to *your* refs over time.

Comment: I tried ````git fetch origin```` and then ````git diff````. Still, getting the same error.
````git checkout master
git fetch origin
git diff --name-status "@{2 days ago}" "@{now}"

warning: Log for 'master' only goes back to Thu, 19 Sep 2019 16:03:29 -0700.````

Comment: Again, you're looking at *your* reflogs. How many entries are in your reflog? What are their dates? (Use `git reflog master` to view these entries.) These are not *refs*, these are *reflogs*.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. I think this answer got so few upvotes only because this is a somewhat new question with relatively low traffic, but it deserves way more. Thanks for taking the time to write it down so clearly.

Answer (score 16):

The `@{xyz}` syntax checks the reflogs, those are logs of what refs have pointed at.  All refs are local.  `@{2.days.ago}` is "what I had checked out in this repo 2 days ago".  If instead you want "the last thing committed to origin's master at least 2 days ago." A good starter kit:

```
git rev-list -1 --before 2.days.ago origin/master
```

Depending on what you're looking for you, might also want `--first-parent` and/or `--author-date-order`.

You can also use specific dates, for instance

```
git checkout `git rev-list -1 --before="Apr 1 2020" HEAD`
```